# There is an entry for table "k", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query. SUBQUERY SQL

Tags: sql, database

i'm writting a sql query but still got the same error and don't know how to solve it.

```
select k.klantnr, aantal
from klanten k INNER JOIN(
select d.klantnr, count(d.reisnr) as aantal
from deelnames d
where k.klantnr = d.klantnr
group by d.klantnr) as adeelnames USING(klantnr)
```

Error :

```
There is an entry for table "k", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

Comment: Remove the where clause from the derived table. It's not needed as you're joining the derived table with the `using` keyword.

Comment: yes but i need a correlated. Or i just need to compare the klantnr from subquery with the klantnr of headquery

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a correlation clause inside the subquery:

```
select klantnr, aantal
from klanten k INNER JOIN
     (select d.klantnr, count(d.reisnr) as aantal
      from deelnames d
      group by d.klantnr
    ) adeelnames
    USING (klantnr);
```

The `USING` clause does everything you need.  Note the removal of `k.` in the `SELECT` as well.

Also, you might want a `LEFT JOIN`, if you want counts of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that klatnr in a unique key in klanten you should be able to just use a join and skip the derived table:

```
select k.klantnr, count(d.reisnr) as aantal
from klanten k join deelnames d using(klantnr)
group by k.klantnr;
```

Comment: I guess this would depend on whether `klantnr` is unique in the `klanten` table. Sidenote: thanks for pointing out the mistake in my post. I was way off :)

Comment: @sstan Yeah, I guess so. Your query wasn't way off at all though, you just needed to remove either the `on` or the `using`

Comment: I was way off because I didn't even know what the `using` clause was doing.  I had never seen or used it before.